# How to get the value from SimpleXMLElement Object which starts with @?

Tags: php, xml

I am stuck in a problem, I want to access a value which comes under the `SimpleXMLElement Object` under `@attributes` category, here is the array:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
  [@attributes] => Array (
    [src] => source/send_smsf.php
    [name] => mainFrame
    [id] => mainFrame
    [title] => mainFrame
  )
)
```

I want to access the `id` attribute inside it. But how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer :

```
$id = $mainNode->attributes()->id;
```

We can place the @attribute in attributes function and then can call any value inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get that object to a variable and access it like this,

```
$id = (string) $object['id']; //$object is the SimpleXMLElement object.
```